# bash script js file selector

Tags: bash, file

I was assigned task to find all the .js files in current directory using bash script . I came up with 
 `find . -name "*.js"`but my mentor given me hint by providing with this code 
 `test="**.js" 
 echo $test` 

can anyone tell me how this code works and which one is accurate solution to the problem ?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: there is no code just bunch of commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical explanation:

- `find . -name "*.js"` runs a *command* which prints the path starting with `./` of files (including "special" files such as directories) matching the [glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) `*.js` anywhere in *and beneath* the current working directory (`pwd` or `$PWD`), printing a newline (or more technically, the *last* character of `$IFS`) after each filename.
- `test="**.js"` saves the *string* `**.js` to a variable called `test`. `echo $test` [*expands*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) the value of the `test` variable in the *shell* to a whitespace-separated (or more technically, the *first* character of `$IFS`) string which is then passed as arguments to the shell built-in `echo`. The second asterisk in the variable is redundant.

If the goal is to loop over the .js files within the current directory, the accepted best practice solution is a `for` loop over a glob:

```
for path in ./*.js
do
    […]
done
```

This handles literally *any* filename, including those with weird characters such as newlines or starting with dashes.

Comment: `**` is different from `*` if the `globstar` shell option is set. At least in bash.

Comment: As @Thomas said, if `globstar` is enabled, `**.js` will search in subdirectories while `*.js` will search in current directory only. This makes a huge difference and this is why @lila's mentor showed this example to be equal to find (find searches in subdirectories).

Comment: Even with `globstar` set (it's off by default), `**.js` doesn't match anything. `**` only matches full path components, so you'd need to do something like `**/*.js`.